# Basic map application results in classNotFoundException

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to build a very simple Google Maps application that just displays the map. While the project builds OK, it force closes on the emulator. The code:

helloMaps.java:

```
package com.example.hellomaps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class helloMaps extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_maps);
       GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
       map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hello_maps, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

helloMaps.manifest:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hellomaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.hellomaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.hellomaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".helloMaps"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_hello_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="api key here"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_hello_maps.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Starting the app results in a classNotFoundException. The logCat output is:

```
05-11 10:43:09.614: D/AndroidRuntime(336): Shutting down VM
05-11 10:43:09.614: W/dalvikvm(336): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-11 10:43:09.614: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hellomaps/com.example.hellomaps.helloMaps}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:582)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.example.hellomaps.helloMaps.onCreate(helloMaps.java:12)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  ... 11 more
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:404)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
05-11 10:43:09.624: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  ... 19 more
05-11 10:43:09.644: I/dalvikvm(336): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
05-11 10:43:09.644: E/dalvikvm(336): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

My questions:
1. How do I make this work?

Comment: what version of google maps api you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your manifest inside the application element:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

For example:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".helloMaps"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hello_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
```

Comment: you will continue to see gray tiles (with zoom controls), as you are trying to use google map API V1 with an API V2 key. this will never work. and you can't produce.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mess with both API's of Google Maps. If you are trying to reference `android-support-v4.jar` am assuming that you are trying to implement Google Maps API V2. Now, if this is the case then you have a lot of problems in your code that are most probably are causing you the `classNotFoundException` error.

for example, you are missing some permissions:

```
<permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"  android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Next, you will have to use the `MapFragment` or the `SupportMapFragment` objects which are Google Maps API v2 objects instead of the `MapView` object you are using right which is API V1 object.

You can get more information on how to implement it's correctly by reading this blog post I wrote on this topic:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

**UPDATE:**

**1.** First of all you don't need to use `SupportMapFragment` if you are targeting `API => 11`.

**2.** Remove this permission:

```
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

It's a **Google Map API V1** permission nad is not needed in **API V2**.

**3.** From your error: `Error inflating class fragment` there is some problem in inflating the fragment.

First of all try to place the fragment within something layout like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If this doesn't help you then most cases you have some problem referencing one of the libraries needed for Google Map API V2, go over my guide again and make sure you are making the first 4 steps correctly.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but is V1 f the Maps API not deprecated?

Comment: You are not wrong, it is deprecated. This brings the question for why you are trying to use it?

Comment: I changed the code to be in line with Google Maps API V2.. it still does not work.. please take a look?